# How to filter a backspace keyboard input

Tags: java, javafx-2

I have this code that gives a message when another key as a number is pressed:

```
txtValueOfClause.addEventFilter(KeyEvent.KEY_TYPED, new EventHandler<KeyEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(KeyEvent t) {
                char ar[] = t.getCharacter().toCharArray();
                char ch = ar[t.getCharacter().toCharArray().length - 1];
                if (!(ch >= '0' && ch <= '9')) {
                    System.out.println("The char you entered is not a number");
                    t.consume();
                }
            }
        });
```

Now if I press on the wrong button and I press backspace to remove it, I also get this error message.
How can I add backspace input into the if statement?

Comment: No what I meant with the error message is this: "System.out.println("The char you entered is not a number");"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found an answer:

```
txtValueOfClause.addEventFilter(KeyEvent.KEY_TYPED, new EventHandler<KeyEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(KeyEvent t) {
                char ar[] = t.getCharacter().toCharArray();
                char ch = ar[t.getCharacter().toCharArray().length - 1];
                int codeBackSpace = ch;
                if (!(ch >= '0' && ch <= '9') && codeBackSpace!=8) {

                    System.out.println("The char you entered is not a number");
                    t.consume();
                }
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess This should work

```
txtValueOfClause.addEventFilter(KeyEvent.KEY_TYPED, new EventHandler<KeyEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(KeyEvent t) {
            char ar[] = t.getCharacter().toCharArray();
            char ch = ar[t.getCharacter().toCharArray().length - 1];
            if (!(ch >= '0' && ch <= '9' && t.getCode().equals(KeyCode.BACK_SPACE))) {
                System.out.println("The char you entered is not a number");
                t.consume();
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Doesnt work If I do System.out.println(t.getCode()); I get "UNDEFINED"

Comment: @Harish, from the JavaDoc: _The key code associated with the key in this key pressed or key released event. For key typed events, code is always KeyCode.UNDEFINED._

Trying to find a new solution myself.